# AutoComplete for Checkbox list using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, filter, checkboxlist

I want to filter CheckBox list using autocomplete functionality in ASP.Net and C#. How do I do it?

Comment: do u mean something like this
[link](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/) ?

Comment: No, I've Text box which i fill from a checkboxlist, each item that is checked will be placed in the textbox. The checkboxlist will appear in a ajax popupControlExtender,Now i need a textbox with a autocomplete function to search tru' the checkboxlist for a specific element.

Answer (score 0):

Here im giving reference links to get an idea not an exact answer.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3_5gnTIS4E

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quQgUNteWxY